# Rails redirect_to in other folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have some actions in other directory (admin/) but how can i redirect to vin_questions path, which is in admin controller? now it gives me error

```
Template is missing
```

my code

```
def create
    @va = VinAnswer.new(params[:vin_answer])
    @va.vin_question_id  = params[:vin_question_id]
    @va.save
    render :layout => 'admin'
    redirect_to  admin_vin_questions_path
  end
```

and part of routes (rake routes)

```
 admin_vin_questions GET    /admin/vin_questions(.:format)                                            admin/vin_questions#index
                                POST   /admin/vin_questions(.:format)                                            admin/vin_questions#create
         new_admin_vin_question GET    /admin/vin_questions/new(.:format)                                        admin/vin_questions#new
        edit_admin_vin_question GET    /admin/vin_questions/:id/edit(.:format)                                   admin/vin_questions#edit
             admin_vin_question GET    /admin/vin_questions/:id(.:format)                                        admin/vin_questions#show
                                PUT    /admin/vin_questions/:id(.:format)                                        admin/vin_questions#update
                                DELETE /admin/vin_questions/:id(.:format)                                        admin/vin_questions#destroy
```

but what's wrong? how redirect to /admin/vin_questions?

> **upd**

```
Template is missing

Missing template admin/vin_answers/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:ru], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/media/_Projects/Oleg/app/views" * "/home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

Comment: do you have a file with the name admin.html.erb in your views/layouts/  folder???

Comment: @Jean sure i have... I get this for example when i try to add new, after submiting (in db is creating)

Comment: it redirects you to :create action of admin/vin_questions controller. But has to :index action, right?. Try redirect_to admin_vin_questions_path(:action => "index")

Comment: @ValeryKvon it must redirect from create to index (after creating)

Comment: By default, request to admin_vin_questions_path with GET http method redirects you you to :index, and with POST to :create. Где-то ошибка.

Comment: and remove "render :layout => 'admin'", it assumes, that action has a template :create.

Comment: @ValeryKvon but how render other layout?

Comment: Obviously, actions :create, :update and :destroy do not have to render their own templates (and layouts). I can only guess that your action :create must either save record and redirect to next action (next GET request), or (if record wasn't saved) render the form again with errors messages. If your form rendered by action :new, so :create action have to 'render :action => "new"'. In this case layout will be of action "new".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def create
  @va = VinAnswer.new(params[:vin_answer])
  @va.vin_question_id  = params[:vin_question_id]
  if @va.save
    redirect_to  admin_vin_questions_path # redirect if saved.
  else
    render :layout => 'admin'  # stay here.
  end
end
```

And set layout in vin_questions controller if it has not.

Comment: added... but also i have all this templates!

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this in the controller

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

layout :resolve_layout

your actions

private

def resolve_layout
  case action_name
  when "index"
    "layoutxxx"
  when "show"
    "layoutzzz"
  when "create"
       "admin"
  else
    "application"
  end
end
```

and erease this line from your create controller

```
render :layout => 'admin'
```